# Calling Ruby method from the command line

Tags: ruby, command-line

I have a program in a file called `project1.rb`. Inside this file I have a method called `check_num(n)`. I simply want to call that method from the command line or IRB, but I can't figure out how and can't seem to find docs explaining how.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$ ruby project1.rb check_num(100)

#=> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can Anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Assuming your `project.rb` file is in the current directory, when in irb type `require './project1.rb'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ruby -r ./project1.rb -e "check_num(100)"
```

`-r filename` is same as Ruby `require "filename"`; and `-e code` evaluates Ruby code.